# Vue.js: How to call a component method automatically when Component loads?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Assuming that I have a component 'test-component' that has a method getGeoEmailData() that fetches some data by making an Ajax call. If I am using the component like this:

```
<test-component v-bind:item="item" ></test-component>
```

I want to call getGeoEmailData() automatically (after parent prop 'item' has been bound to the component prop 'item') How do I do this?

Comment: you mean if `item` is true, you want to get something from `getGeoEmailData` from inside the component?

Comment: Call it in the [created](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want to get a data from inside your component, you have to emit from withing the components methods using it using emit method ex:

```
methods: {
  emitSomething () {
    this.$emit('foobar', 'some data')
  }
}
```

Now from your component you can listen listen event and pass it to your local methods using this syntax:

```
<my-component v-on:foobar='handler'></my-component>
```

Now just created a method called handler to get what is emitted from the child.

If you want to get the emit content once your component binds to a value, just use a watcher: {} to watch when property is set to true.

This example will show you how when `item` changes to true, you can get the emit from the child component.

```js
Vue.component ('my-component', {
  template: `<p> </p>`,
  props: ['item'],
  watch: {
    item (val) {
      if(val) {
        this.getSomething(); 
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSomething () {
     this.$emit('onitembind', 'I AM EMITTED FROM CHILD')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
   return {
      item: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    acceptDataFromChild(event) {
      console.log('event:', event)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click='item = !item'> {{ item ? 'stop' : 'get' }} data from child </button>
  <my-component :item='item' @onitembind='acceptDataFromChild'></my-component>
</div>
```

You can check your console to see that every time the `item` prop changes to `true` an event will be emitted from child component and the parent catches it using `acceptDataFromChild`. The stop is redundant, as it only toggles the state of item to false. But this should work for your case